# jacoco.xml vs jacocoTestReport.xml

Tags: gradle, jacoco

In my gradle project, I have `jacocoTestReport.xml`  instead of `jacoco.xml` .
What are the differences between `jacoco.xml` vs `jacocoTestReport.xml` ?

On Google, the difference between both file are not clear.

PS: the reason I'm asking is that **Code Climate** expects a `jacoco.xml` file for the code coverage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Gradle task of type `JacocoReport` uses name of task for name of `xml` file - https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v5.5.1/subprojects/jacoco/src/main/java/org/gradle/testing/jacoco/plugins/JacocoPlugin.java#L278-L282

Destination file can be customized - for example `jacocoTestReport` task in following `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "jacoco"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        xml.destination = file("build/foo.xml")
    }
}
```

configured to produce file `build/foo.xml` instead of default `build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml`.